# Data validation if no then disable cell else drop-down lists

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I'm trying to do a drop-down list IF another cell doesn't equal "no"
So I have two columns: one with a drop-down list containing "yes" and "no" and in the other column I want to do a drop-down list only if the previous column is different than "no".

I tried many things, googling all the internet but doesn't find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

**Y1: `=IF(A1="yes", {C1:C}, )`**

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mG9D2bCTicg-82Tygz_TK3HdKs1Wueri3rWsOocl7zQ/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: hmm i'm on excel but anyway, the problem is that I don't want "c" column and when A is "yes" B should be a dropdown list not just print "aa bb cc"

Comment: @Joop answer updated